# What the equivalent of PreExecution in RXJava2?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I create an Observable that runs every 20 seconds.
I need to show the progress Bar (UI component) before every round, in AsyncTask i used onPreExecute method.
How can I do that in RXJava2 ?

```
 disposables = Observable
 .interval(0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .doOnNext(n -> MainCulc_actions())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // Run on a background thread
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())     // Be notified on the main thread
   .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Long>() {

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {
      }
      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
      }
      @Override
      public void onNext(Long res) {
        UpdateTheUI();
        avi.smoothToHide();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `doOnSubscribe`. For example

```
disposables = Observable
.interval(0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.doOnNext(n -> MainCulc_actions())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // Run on a background thread
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())     // Be notified on the main thread
.doOnSubscribe(s -> avi.showUI)
.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Long>() {

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
  }
  @Override
  public void onNext(Long res) {
    UpdateTheUI();
    avi.smoothToHide();
  }
});
```